# Client certificate passing issue into REST API from .NET Application which hosted in AWS IIS

Tags: c#, .net, rest, iis, ssl-certificate

Hi i am facing one issue to pass certificates into Rest API. I have 2 files private key and public key and I have created a .pfx file using those 2 keys and certificate pass is working fine in the visual studioand local IIS.

But the issue is in the AWS server IIS. Somehow the certificate passed not going through in the server and getting below error from the Rest API.

Error: An error occurred while sending the request The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

I am using below code to generate a certificate and pass into rest api.

> X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(Server.MapPath("~/Certificate/certificate.pfx"));
>
> var handler = new HttpClientHandler
> {
> ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual,
> SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12
> };
> handler.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
>
> HttpClient httpClient;
>
> httpClient = new HttpClient(handler)
> {
> BaseAddress = new Uri("xxxxxxxx"),
> };
> httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
> httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new
> MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
>
> var httpResponse = httpClient.PostAsync("xxxxxxxx", new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;
> var httpResponseContent = httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result

It's something like from below line its goes to catch block:

> var httpResponse = httpClient.PostAsync("xxxxxxxx", new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;

In the server TLS1.2 is enabled and file read permission etc are ok. I have upload those .key and .pem file in the Amazon Certificate Manager (ACM) also. So not sure why that error is coming. Can someone help me on this issue please. I am really struggling with this issue but not getting any clue where it is blocked.

Comment: Could you please download and install iis crypto tool from the below link:
https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto/Download
And set the best practice and reboot the machine:[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKnLO.png)

Comment: @JalpaPanchal Actually we are using AWS and windows server 2010. Is this any effect in total system? Its something like a software run to udpate registery etc.

Comment: yes this will update registry key to modify the TLS version and Cipher Suites

Comment: @JalpaPanchal In IIS TLS1.2 is enable and remote API only accept the TLS1.2.

Comment: yes i have read this detail from the post. apart from the version we also have to apply the right cipher suites which is not possible and recommended to manually modify by the registry key

Comment: if this is your production environment you can apply the changes first in the dev and make test

Comment: @JalpaPanchal That software not only related to change setting for specific domain. Its basicaly will change whole registery in that AWS server. This is what i am little bit concern.

Comment: if you are afraid of the registry key configuration you can try this code "ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls
       | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11
       | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
       | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;"

Comment: @JalpaPanchal Actually i have tried with that already but no luck. Same result. 
The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

Comment: could you make a test for the ssl certificate on this website and see the result https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest